# KrbException: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds

Tags: linux, tomcat, kerberos, sql

I am working on setting up Tomcat 8.0.35 on Ubuntu 16.04 with Oracle Java 1.8.0_91-b14 (not `openjdk`) to use Kerberos authentication when authenticating to our Microsoft SQL database. The issue I am running into is that after running `kinit` as the appropriate user with the appropriate switches:

```
sudo -u tomcat8 kinit -k -t /etc/tomcat8/tomcat8.keytab HTTP/linux-test2.our.domain.local@OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL
```

I am getting this error in the localhost log from Tomcat:

```
Caused by: GSSException: No valid credentials provided (Mechanism level: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds)
Caused by: KrbException: Fail to create credential. (63) - No service creds
```

When I run

```
sudo -u tomcat8 klist
```

I get the expected response:

```
root@linux-test2:/home/tbourne# sudo -u tomcat8 klist
Ticket cache: FILE:/tmp/krb5cc_111
Default principal: HTTP/linux-test2.our.domain.local@OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL

Valid starting       Expires              Service principal
06/23/2016 14:33:10  06/24/2016 00:33:10  krbtgt/OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL@OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL
        renew until 06/24/2016 14:33:07
```

When I capture packets during the Tomcat startup, I see a service/instance name being passed of `krbtgt/OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL`. I was expecting this to be the Default Principal mentioned above. When I set the `serverSpn` option in the database connection string, I get the above results.

When I remove the `serverSpn` option, it uses a different Principal name `MSSQLSvc/sql-server.our.domain.local@OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL`. Unfortunately I can't use that name since I will need unique logins (and thereby unique SPNs) for each of our Tomcat instances.

Our database connection string looks like this:

```
property.db.driverClassName=com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver
property.db.jdbcUrl=jdbc:sqlserver://sql-server.our.domain.local:1434;databaseName=DBAUTH2;integratedSecurity=true;authenticationScheme=JavaKerberos;serverSpn="HTTP/linux-test2.our.domain.local@OUR.DOMAIN.LOCAL"
```

I have downloaded the Microsoft JDBC driver version 4.2 and Tomcat is using it.

I am at a loss as to why Tomcat isn't sending the proper principal name when authenticating to the database. Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

I can post the `krb5.ini` for Tomcat, the `krb5.conf`, the `jaas.conf` and any other configs if they would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

The Kerberos configuration file (`/etc/krb5.conf`) is case-sensitive and changing the `default_realm` name to lowercase [will cause this problem](https://help.mulesoft.com/s/article/sun-security-krb5-internal-KrbApErrException-Fail-to-create-credential-63-No-service-creds).